# What's the type of maps and Where I can find a example or tutorial

Tags: google-maps

Hello everyone Please Where I can find a tutorial for this kinf of maps[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsdVX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start with Google's official documentation. The map shown in that picture is a Google map loaded via the [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Then, to highlight a specific region you can use [overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays) such as polygons.

Note that you will need to enable billing and [set up your project](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#setup-procedures) properly before you can start using the Maps APIs.

Hope this helps you get started!